# i am trying to fill a pdf form through java code to generate dynamic filled form for different customers

Tags: java, pdfbox

My code is like :

```
// Open file
        File file=new File("abc.pdf");
        newdoc=new PDDocument();        
        doc=PDDocument.load(file);  


//Select Page
    int pageIndex=0;
    newpage=newdoc.getPage(pageIndex);
    content=new PDPageContentStream(newdoc, newpage);
    content.drawString(text);
```

1. Why details which i filled, are reflecting to all pages
2. I need to tick few checkMarks in form. How to do that in java?
    for ex: 1.java 2.c++ 3.Python I need to make a tick mark on java for all users.
   For this, I am using pdfbox-app library. the problem is changes are reflecting for all pages, but I want to edit only first page.??

Help me with this, please. 
If you are not able to understand my question then please let me know.

Comment: Please edit your question... it is unclear what you want to do. You're opening a PDF, creating another, getting the first page several times, creating a content stream, doing nothing, then doing this again, ...? You mention "changes". What changes? Re checkmarks, see the SetField.java example in the source code download or here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/SetField.java?view=markup&sortby=date

Comment: Your edit hasn't improved clarity: now you're closing a content stream that you have never created. The text "Why this is not selecting only first page and changes are reflected to all page" does not make any sense - you haven't made any changes to the existing file. (And why do you open an existing file and create another??) Maybe concentrate on a single question, explain what you expected and what happened instead. Your code should at least compile.

Comment: you want something like [this](https://www.daedtech.com/programatically-filling-out-pdfs-in-java/)?

Comment: Concerning **1**: because you are doing something wrong. Provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your issue for a more detailed analysis. Concerning **2**: `PDCheckBox` has a `check` method.